# Smooth Scroll pixel steps

Tags: javascript, html, css

i need a liitle help here. I copyed this javascript including html and css form jsfiddle to use it in a matched form for my site. But if i copy the code from this side where it is working and try it out before matching it doesnt work. Following the code i copied, where is the fault??

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 TRANSITIONAL//EN">
<html><head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="scroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="css.css">
</head> 
<body>
<a id="scrollUp" href="#">up</a>
<a id="scrollDown" href="#">down</a>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <ul>
            <li>some content here</li>
            <li>some content here</li>
            <li>some content here</li>
            <li>some content here</li>
            <li>some content here</li>
            <li>some content here</li>
            <li>some content here</li>
            <li>some content here</li>
            <li>some content here</li>
            <li>some content here</li>
            <li>some content here</li>
            <li>some content here</li>
            <li>some content here</li>
            <li>some content here</li>
            <li>some content here</li>
            <li>some content here</li>
            <li>some content here</li>
            <li>some content here</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#content {
    overflow:auto;
    height: 90px;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var step = 25;
var scrolling = false;

// Wire up events for the 'scrollUp' link:
$("#scrollUp").bind("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Animates the scrollTop property by the specified
    // step.
    $("#content").animate({
        scrollTop: "-=" + step + "px"
    });
}).bind("mouseover", function (event) {
    scrolling = true;
    scrollContent("up");
}).bind("mouseout", function (event) {
    scrolling = false;
});


$("#scrollDown").bind("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#content").animate({
        scrollTop: "+=" + step + "px"
    });
}).bind("mouseover", function (event) {
    scrolling = true;
    scrollContent("down");
}).bind("mouseout", function (event) {
    scrolling = false;
});

function scrollContent(direction) {
    var amount = (direction === "up" ? "-=1px" : "+=1px");
    $("#content").animate({
        scrollTop: amount
    }, 1, function () {
        if (scrolling) {
            scrollContent(direction);
        }
    });
}
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Are you including JQuery anywhere? It appears to be missing and you're calling JQuery functions.

Comment: yes also tryed including jquery but still doesnt working. Added in head <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> and downloaded this file from jquery.com

Comment: Instead of hosting it yourself, try including this in your head: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` By using Google's version, most of your visitors will already have it cached and it will improve load time.

Comment: added your line istead of the other one, but still not working.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: no, no errors are shown

Answer (score 0):

try replacing `bind` for `on`.

As it says in the reference page;

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for
>   attaching event handlers to a document.

Comment: I just tried your code in jsfiddle and including the jquery library works, so I am quite sure something in that point is not correct

Comment: i copied the code form jsfiddle as i said and it is working there so thats exactly the point. I doent know where the problem is, it should be working but it doesnt

Comment: I know what you said, and what I said is that you have a problem including jquery in your page. Check for errors in the console

Comment: i added this line <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> to include jquery in head betwenn the meta-tag and the style-tag of the scroll.js. dont get any errors in console but if i move mouse over up or down nothing is happening by clicking it does nothing s well

Comment: type this line in the console and see if you get the jQuery version
jQuery.fn.jquery

Answer (score 0):

Your script is loaded in the header, but the elements to which it refers #scrollUp and #scrollDown are not loaded until later in the page.
Since you are using jquery, try putting your javascript in a document ready function.
i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Your code
});
```